# Using mathematical induction to show the following property of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I asked to show that 
The $\overline{
 z_1+ z_2 +\ldots + z_n} = \overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2} +\ldots + \overline{z_n}$ ; for $n= 2,3,\ldots$

using mathematical induction.

My question is :-

As mathematical induction, we take first step to verify for n=1, here I am asked to show that the property holds for n=2,3,...; should I verify this for n=2 in step 1? because taking n=1 as first step of induction is meaningless. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case your base case has to be $n=2$.

Comment: Not meaningless, but trivial - which makes for a shorter proof. If I were facing that task I might even start at $n=0$, just for the fun of it :) Of course the tool to make the induction step $n\to n+1$ is the $n=2$ case anyway, no matter where you start. -- (On second reading: The problem statement specifically *asks* for a proof for $n=2,3,\ldots$. In that case I agree that you should use $n=2$ as base case - but still sometimes one might look out for simplifications of the proof by proving more than requested, i.e.,  by lowering the base case. Clear sign is if parts of the proof are double